# MATCH/EXACT Function with Array of Length One

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use the MATCH and EXACT function with an array of length one.

Say I have the value 'a' in B1, and the value 'a' in C1.
When I enter the following formula in A1, I get the NA error:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(B1,$C$1:$C$1))
```

However, if I change the formula to

```
=MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(B1,$C$1:$C$2))
```

Match returns 1.

My question is: does match work with arrays of length 2 or more, or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: You simply write `=MATCH(B1,C1:C1,0)` ,, returns `1` or if Matching CASE then `=EXACT(B1,C1)` !

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the answer.

Comment: I think that you post wrong facts. As [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/exact-function-d3087698-fc15-4a15-9631-12575cf29926) claims both arguments of EXACT() must be single strings, not arrays. So `=MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(B1,$C$1:$C$1))` must work (1-cell range is a value, it is valid) whereas `=MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(B1,$C$1:$C$2))` must give `#N/A` error (multi-cell range is 2-dimentional array, it is not valid).

Comment: Oddly, this works in LibreOffice, though it doesn't seem as though it should, since `=EXACT()` expects a scalar as its second parameter and returns a scalar, whereas `=MATCH()` expects an array as its second parameter. In its simplest form `=MATCH(1,1)` returns an error in both LO and Excel. The only version I have of Excel is 2007, and that gives `#N/A` on both formulae, which is more consistent. You must have other, unstated constraints, because I see nothing wrong with @RajeshS's suggestion of `=EXACT(B1,C1)`. It's what I'd do.

Comment: @MuathAlqurashi,, now check my post,,, it solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

*Since you are trying to work with Case sensitive feature, then this will solve the issue.*

- No need to use **MATCH** since **EXACT** is been used.

[image]

- An Array Formula in Cell `A175:`

`{=AND(EXACT(B175:D175,B175))}`

**N.B.**

- Finish Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.
- You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.

Comment: I am looking for answer to the question, not a different way of approaching the problem.

Comment: @MuathAlqurashi, *this solution itself is the answer,, remember the `MATCH` with Array can be used but will be for `CASE insensitive` & you are trying `CASE sensitive`*, therefore I've suggested few through comments and this one too. `MATCH` with others like  `INDEX` can be used to get multiple Rows as an Array formula !!

Comment: **Cont..** and your second Formula returns `2` all the time if `C1 & C2` does have `a` in both or `A` & `a` or even `a` & `b` or `B` !!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the formula you're looking for is `FIND`. This formula is similar to `MATCH` and is Case-Sensitive.

So your formula would be `=FIND(B1,$C$1)`

Please comment below is this is not what you're looking for.